# lost?/corrupted? seagate 500Gb external disk

Tags: xubuntu, data-recovery, disk, password-recovery

I am not expert and need a patient guide.
History of events:

1. Only XP in internal disk with documents on a seagate 500Gb
2. Installed Ubuntu by partitioning external disk and booting from it
3. During XP use, seagate repeatedly autorun and making a click sound.  Ubuntu no longer accessible.
4. Internal hard disk partitioned and Xubuntu installed.  Xubuntu FileSystem can only see one of the partitions on seagate, which contains a folder Lost&Found but won't let me access it because it is owned by Root and when i open a terminal window and type "su" i get Authentication failure when i type in the only password i have ever given it.  Yet i can install new packages with Administrator password.
5. Testdisk can't see any partitions on seagate disk !!

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with ddrescue on drives that made clicking noises, but if you have a backup then consider the seagate drive a lost cause, buy another drive and restore from backups.  If you don't have backups, give ddrescue a shot -- it will attempt to read the disk repeatedly to access bad areas of the disk, but learn from your mistake and make sure you keep backups in the future. I had to learn the hard way, it's never fun.

ddrescue: http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html